# For what non trivial values of $a$ and $k$, $a^k + 1$ will be prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> For what non trivial values of $a$ and $k$, $a^k + 1$ will be prime?

If $a=1$, then $1^k+1=1+1=2$, where 2 is prime.
If $k=1$ then we have$a^k+1=a+1$, but if some prime $p$ is equal to $a+1$, then only we can say $a+1$ is prime.

But for the rest part I am clueless to proceed. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Is it similar to the problem $2^{2^n}+1$ is prime for even $n$?

Comment: This is a serious open question just for $a=2$ - read about Fermat primes at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number

Comment: What are you hoping for here?  Nobody knows much about questions like this.

Comment: Everyone knows that $a$ must be even; and $k$ cannot have an odd factor greater than $1$ - see Sonnhard's answer for why.  So you have some of the numbers $(2m)^{2^n}+1$.  Which ones, no-one knows much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consider the case $k=3$ then we get $$a^3+1=(a+1)(1-a+a^2)$$

Comment: Would you like to elaborate this hint a **little** please?

Comment: for some cases it is easy to solve, and if $a\geq 2$ it states that $a^3+1$ Can never be a prime

Comment: Okay. I think I got the hint. Thank you (+1)

Comment: you Can search for $k$ for which $$a^k+1$$ Can be factorized

Comment: Yes, I am following that way

Comment: Let $a,k$ be even, let $k=2^{k_1{^{k_2}}}$, where , $k_2$ is odd. which gives $a^k+1$ may be prime if $k_2=1$. For odd $k$, $a^k+1$ is not a prime - that's what your hint says.